# nixOS: how to recover from collision between two instances of same package, same version

Tags: haskell, nixos, nixpkgs

Here is my `nixos` version:

```
$ nixos-version 
16.09pre85931.125ffff (Flounder)
```

Here is my shell script:

```
$ cat test.nix 
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {
}, compiler ? "ghc801" }:

let
  inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;
  ghc = pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler}.ghcWithPackages (ps: with ps; [
    diagrams
    diagrams-pgf
  ]);
in
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "test";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    ghc
  ];
  shellHook = ''
    eval $(egrep ^export ${ghc}/bin/ghc)
  '';
}
```

Here is the problem. Note that there is a collision between two instances of the same version of the same package:

```
$ nix-shell --pure test.nix 
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/r6080kvlvdb16c1frz8alnm14xjizkf5-ghc-8.0.1.drv
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/1129nds6xhq6hqawdd2s9z9n6va57jgl-ghc-8.0.1’
collision between `/nix/store/amdnmbd8p52d49bqmphv9f7ly7lf7pkk-active-0.2.0.10/share/doc/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.1/active-0.2.0.10/html/Data-Active.html' and `/nix/store/yniw6akz2ldimdlj9yq968ldaf4j18h1-active-0.2.0.10/share/doc/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.1/active-0.2.0.10/html/Data-Active.html'
builder for ‘/nix/store/r6080kvlvdb16c1frz8alnm14xjizkf5-ghc-8.0.1.drv’ failed with exit code 255
error: build of ‘/nix/store/r6080kvlvdb16c1frz8alnm14xjizkf5-ghc-8.0.1.drv’ failed
/run/current-system/sw/bin/nix-shell: failed to build all dependencies
```

I know that if the packages had different versions then I could do something like this:

```
$ nix-env --set-flag priority 15 <package>-<version>
```

But since the package names and versions are the same, I don't know what to do.

How can I recover from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to reproduce your issue at nixpkgs commit `125ffff`, I get a different error. Namely:

```
src/System/Texrunner/Online.hs:45:1: warning: [-Wunused-imports]
    The import of ‘Control.Applicative’ is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from ‘Control.Applicative’
    To import instances alone, use: import Control.Applicative()
[3 of 3] Compiling System.Texrunner ( src/System/Texrunner.hs, dist/build/System/Texrunner.o )

src/System/Texrunner.hs:18:1: warning: [-Wunused-imports]
    The import of ‘Control.Applicative’ is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from ‘Control.Applicative’
    To import instances alone, use: import Control.Applicative()
Preprocessing test suite 'tests' for texrunner-0.0.1.1...
[1 of 2] Compiling Tex.PDF          ( tests/Tex/PDF.hs, dist/build/tests/tests-tmp/Tex/PDF.dyn_o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( tests/Tests.hs, dist/build/tests/tests-tmp/Main.dyn_o )

tests/Tests.hs:5:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Tex.LogParse’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
builder for ‘/nix/store/g3mwscrvwsr9zrr5h14d59w7nh06qmsw-texrunner-0.0.1.1.drv’ failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation ‘/nix/store/9las78qbxqrlhakhdiqwc2jf7g6i5688-ghc-8.0.1.drv’: 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of ‘/nix/store/9las78qbxqrlhakhdiqwc2jf7g6i5688-ghc-8.0.1.drv’ failed
```

This leads me to believe that `<nixpkgs>` points to a different commit on your machine.
The above issue was fixed at commit `7c7417`. As of commit `80224e` (master at the time of writing) that change is still active. At that point I can reproduce your error.

The issue there seems to be, that `diagrams` and `diagrams-pgf`, as separate packages, depend on different versions of `optparse-applicative`. The package `diagrams-pgf` has its whole scope overriden with the newer version, meaning that it also introduces different versions of `diagrams` and other dependencies. That seems to cause the collision.

A simple fix for you should be to only depend on `diagrams-pgf` in your nix-shell. Most of diagrams will be pulled in as a dependency of `diagrams-pgf` and will therefore still be available.

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {
}, compiler ? "ghc801" }:

let
  inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;
  ghc = pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler}.ghcWithPackages (ps: with ps; [
    diagrams-pgf # <--- HERE
  ]);
in
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "test";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    ghc
  ];
  shellHook = ''
    eval $(egrep ^export ${ghc}/bin/ghc)
  '';
}
```

As confirmed by `ghc --show-packages`:

```
$ ghc --show-packages | grep 'name: diagrams'
name: diagrams-lib
name: diagrams-solve
name: diagrams-core
name: diagrams-pgf
```

Unfortunately, the package `diagrams-svg`, which is pulled in by `diagrams`, fails to build with the new version of `optparse-applicative`. So, it is currently not possible to build an environment with both `diagrams` and `diagrams-pgf` without patching some of these packages.

If you need `diagrams-contrib`, then the following should do the trick:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import ~/src/nixpkgs {}
, compiler ? "ghc801" }:

let
  inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;
  ghc = pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler}.ghcWithPackages (ps: with ps; [
    (diagrams-contrib.overrideScope (self: super: {
      optparse-applicative = self.optparse-applicative_0_13_0_0;
    })) # <--- HERE
    diagrams-pgf
  ]);
in
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "test";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    ghc
  ];
  shellHook = ''
    eval $(egrep ^export ${ghc}/bin/ghc)
  '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ghcWithPackages` effectively creates a brand new distribution of GHC, customised to include the packages you've listed. That is a different thing from `pkgs.ghc`, not just a thing that depends on it; it doesn't make sense to install both into the same environment. I think you've accidentally referred to both, and that's what's causing the collision.

First you make your personal GHC and bring it into scope as the name `ghc`, using `let`.

Inside the scope of the `let` you say:

```
buildInputs = with pkgs; [
  ghc
];
```

The `with` brings every attribute of `pkgs` into scope for the following expression. `pkgs` has a `ghc` attribute, and the `with` scope is the innermost scope containing a `ghc` binding, so that takes precedence over the `ghc` from the `let`.

Your `shellHook` on the other hand is outside the scope of the `with`. So the `${ghc}` is a reference to your let-bound `ghc`. This makes your derivation depend on that, too.

If that's correct, the solution would be either:

1. Remove the `with`, so the build inputs list sees the same `ghc` as the rest of your code (using qualified references for anything else from `pkgs` you haven't included here)
2. Move the `with` outside the `let`, so your version of `ghc` is the innermost binding (but then you pollute the namespace of your whole file with everything from `pkgs`, which gets confusing when it gets more complicated)
3. In your `let` use a different variable name (`myghc` or something) and refer to that everywhere

Comment: @helpwithhaskell Ah, I might have been wrong about the cause then. I'm on my phone atm, which sadly doesn't run nix, so I can't debug right now.